# How to continue execution after Assert.fail in catch block

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, assertion

My code block is getting terminated after Assert.fail. But  I need to continue execution to make the login page available for next test case

I tried handling,using Assert.fail after my normal execution but Screenshot of login page is captured where the actual failure didnt happen

```
public void getActivityApprovalPending() {
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(activity));
        assertEquals(activity.getText(),"Approval Pending");
        viewTransaction.click();
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", amp.user);
        amp.getUser();
        amp.getLogout();
        Assert.fail("Transaction not in approval pending activity");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue your execution even after assertion failure, use soft assert instead of assert (Its called Hard Assert).

```
// Create an Soft assert type object
SoftAssert softassert = new SoftAssert();
```

Can use any assertion method :
E.g.

```
softassert.fail("I am fail")
// It will cause failure but cont. executing next lines of code.
```

Comment: I need to capture screenshot where the test fails using Listeners, means where assert fails. If I add Hard assert at the end it will capture after the execution and Same happens for soft assert.